# Can not create or open *.VC.db file in VS 2015 (express for desktop) update 3RC

Tags: c++, ios

Today I have upgraded the Visual Studio 2015 (express for desktop) from update 1 to update 3 RC. When I open one of my solutions, it displays an error message: 
“An error occurred while creating or opening the C++ browsing database file *.VC.db. IntelliSense and browsing information will not be available for C++ projects. Remedy(s) to try: Ensure that no other applications are accessing the file. If this problem persists, delete the file and reopen the solution.”
I found that the size of the file *.VC.db is always 0. I have deleted it and reopen the solution again, the problem still there. And the IntelliSense in Option->Text Editor-> C/C++->Advanced are also enabled. Other setting seems also correct. 
At this moment I cannot return back to update1, because the VS2015 online installer seems automatically include the update 3 RC.
Is there anybody know how to solve this problem? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think I had the same issue as you, and it was completely preventing me from using Intellisense. Enabling the database at all caused Visual Studio to hang completely. I suspect the problem is related to the *.VC.VC.opendb lock file. Deleting this file and the .VC.db file did not solve my problem.

My fix: Open the solution, go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced, set Enable New Database Engine to False, and restart Visual Studio. While this immediately solved the problem, I found that I was able to re-enable the new SQLite-backed database engine (which Microsoft [claims is faster](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update2-vs#Cdoubleplus)) and restart Visual Studio, and the problem hasn't surfaced again.

Comment: Looks like they changed the name of the option from "Enable New Database Engine" to "Disable Database" in VS2017, I set that to true then was able to delete the .vs folder. Then I was able to re-open the solution and re-enable the database to get it back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Try Opening the visual studio in Administrator mode. The issue might go away.